# Text result of TEXTJOIN is longer than the limit of 50000 characters

Tags: google-sheets

I m using this formula, its working good in all columns but one is showing the error: **"Text result of TEXTJOIN is longer than the limit of 50000 characters"** Please help me the solve the issue. I mean It was working fine an hour ago and now suddenly error.

For reference, the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QFs4C_bXYJcIPvrCW9h6s6OK7U9etvDAWZ9R1ZfKPgI/edit

Column U is showing error, rest is working fine.

Comment: Cell N2 references another spreadsheet. Has the amount of data in this sheet changed? BTW, it is very difficult to troubleshoot a formula when one doesn't know the content of the referenced external spreadsheet.

Comment: It would return error because of the limits. Better tell what you want to get with that formula.

Comment: See I was using that formula, it was working fine. Now it has again gone crazy automatically. I want to get the dates there according to the count given in M column. Actually, According to that, I have filled up entries in the next sheet, If I change anything now things will go haywire in the next one.

Comment: Use L column, In N column I was trying something to work.

Comment: I don't know where the limits came from? It was working fine.